React Query doesn't re-render after setQueryData
I am kinda new in react-query but what I am trying to implement is the following:
Perform a mutation -> Cache the response data -> access the data to a key.
The component I want to access the data:
function Test() {
  const client = useQueryClient()
  const bla = client.getQueryData(['auth'])

  console.log('blaa', bla)

  return (
    <div>
      <TestInsideTest />
    </div>
  )
}

The component that performs the mutation:
function TestInsideTest() {
  const loginMutation = useLoginMutation()

  return (
    <div>
      I am the test inside test press the button <br />
      <button onClick={() => loginMutation.mutate()}>Do fetch</button>
    </div>
  )
}

The mutation:
export const useLoginMutation = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => Promise.resolve({ access_token: '123' }),
    onSuccess: (data: { access_token: string }) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData(['auth'], data)
    },
  })
}

Once I press the button, the console doesn't do anything, but If i hot reload it seems to get the data correctly. Am I missing something?
You can test it here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-query-forked-x358vl?file=%2Fsrc%2FTest.tsx%3A8%2C27

React query will not notify about the changes in cache to queryClient.GetQueryData. You need to use useQuery

To ensure that you're accessing the latest data after the mutation has completed, you can use the isFetching or isSuccess flags provided by React Query.
import { useQueryClient, useQuery, useMutation } from 'react-query';

function Test() {
  const client = useQueryClient();
  const { data: authData, isSuccess } = useQuery(['auth']);

  console.log('blaa', authData);

  return (
    <div>
      {isSuccess && (
        <div>
          Auth Data: {authData.access_token}
        </div>
      )}
      <TestInsideTest />
    </div>
  );
}

function TestInsideTest() {
  const loginMutation = useLoginMutation();

  return (
    <div>
      I am the test inside test press the button <br />
      <button onClick={() => loginMutation.mutate()}>Do fetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export const useLoginMutation = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => Promise.resolve({ access_token: '123' }),
    onSuccess: (data: { access_token: string }) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData(['auth'], data);
    },
  });
};


Accepting this based on @quyentho answer. You must use useQuery or else react components won't be notified simply by cache changes. Thank you both :)
